# How to use tf.nn.top_k in a keras loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have some issues making this custom loss function (it checks if `y_pred` data is ordered coherently with the real ordering indices provided by `y_true`) work:

```
def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
    ordered_output = tf.cast(tf.nn.top_k(-y_pred, k=5)[1], tf.float32)
    return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(ordered_output - y_true), axis=-1))
```

I can properly run it with sample data:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(custom_objective(tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 
                           tf.constant([0.0, 0.9, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8])).eval())  # 1.82574
```

But somehow it doesn't work if I use it in `model.compile`, as it raises:

```
/Users/luca/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    358   else:
    359     if values is None:
--> 360       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
    361     # if dtype is provided, forces numpy array to be the type
    362     # provided if possible.

ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Note that there is no "None" values in my training test set if I change `ordered_output = tf.cast(tf.nn.top_k(-y_pred, k=5)[1], tf.float32)` to `ordered_output = -y_pred` the model compiles fine and starts training properly (but it's clearly not the loss function I want).

I have the subtle feeling that there might be something wrong in using `top_k` in a loss function as I don't see how it could be differentiable, but I don't have better ideas for evaluating differences in predicted ordering. Hints/ideas/papers/references? :)

Comment: is `y_true` an order data or indeces of ordered data?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko the second. y is originally ordered, then it's shuffled before training and y_true represents the indices of the ordered data that I want to predict. atm I am defaulting to using MSE to predict it, but it's not super efficient

Comment: I may show you on how to rewrite your model to optimize it to get the result you want. Currently - your model might do this poorly.

Comment: I was asking the same question to myself tonight: "Is top-k differentiable somehow?" I ran into [this sister site answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280757/differentiable-top-k-function) that had a comment pointing to [this paper with a differentiable top-k approximation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.06504.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

This might be voted down as I won't really fix your code but here goes nothing :

I don't believe, indeed, that you can use top_k as an objective function. Just like you can't use the accuracy as an objective function.

The reason is mathematical. Even if keras, tensorflow, theano and co. are awesome tools for AI and allows everybody to fiddle with neural nets, the latters still remain very complex mathematical tools. Those maths are well hidden under the hood but you should be aware of them when trying to go further than prefabricated tools.

What happens when you train a network is that you compute how wrong the network is on an example and you backpropagate that error to learn from it. The algorithms behind that backpropagation are optimizers, more precisely they are **gradient** based optimizers. Computing a gradient requires to differentiate the function that we are optimizing, the loss/objective function. It means that the objective **must be differentiable**. The accuracy isn't a differentiable function, it takes as an input a real number between 0 and 1 and outputs a step-like function : 0 if x<0.5 and 1 if x>0.5. That function isnt differentiable because we can't get its gradient in 0.5. The top_k function is some kind of accuracy function. So indeed in my opinion you cannot use it in an objective, because under the hood, the smart tensorflow has to compute the gradients of your function.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks again for you help / input Nassim, what you say makes perfectly sense and was also what I expected. Nevertheless I have seen people playing with neural networks that sort stuff and I was wondering if there was a smart approach to this kind of problems. For example a "weak" alternative for checking would be to use MSE or Categorical Crossentropy, but I would lose quite a few information about the ordering of the data.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you're trying to achieve ? A small example of inputs, targets and why you want to do it would be perfect !